# CustomSimpleCursorAdapter vs ViewBinder?

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, custom-adapter, android-viewbinder

I have a list of items which is fetched from the local database. Every item has property `isNew`. I want to make visible `TextView` with text "new" only for items which match `isNew = true`. I solve this problem with two ways, and now I want to know which is best method.

## Method 1:

I write a class `MyViewBinder` which implements `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder` and overrides `public boolean setViewValue(view, cursor, columnIndex)` method with my logic next to that.

## Method 2:

Create `MySimpleCursorAdapter` which extends `SimpleCursorAdapter`, overwrite `getView` method and wrote logic there.

Now I'm working with the second method. Can anyone suggest me which is the best method or if there any other best methods.

Comment: This doesnt seem fit for SO. Just use the one that works better.

Comment: @Cole Johnson, both methods works, I think first is better, but don't sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, depending on the value of the column is necessary to make many changes over the item in the list, the second method is more convenient.